# Moving Frames in the Main Timeline from Inside a Movie Clip

Tags: actionscript-2

I've got an animation inside 1 frame of my main timeline (the animation is inside a movie clip).  Once this animation is done, I want flash to move to the next frame of the main timeline, and stop.

What code do I use here?  I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code ended up being

> `_root.gotoAndPlay(3);`